# CSS Content overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlap, fluid

im having this issue.. keep in mind i'm no expert in CSS i just did my best i could to make a website for my company.
The problem is when i resize the site or view it on XAMPP with ipad its all overlaped!
i want it to stop moving and show scroll bars like normal site would not overlap content!
however when its full screen its fine its on my 1920x1080 monitor.

my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

body
{
    height: 900px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(Images/bkg.jpg);
}

.header
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(Images/header.jpg);
    border-bottom: #CCC 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #F00;
}

.logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -203px;
}

#dog
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 244;
    height: 500;
    top: 15%;
}

.buttonholder
{
    Width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -230px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#textholder
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 35%;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    width: 650px;
    height: 300px;
}

#galleryholder
{
    width: 460px;
    height: 284px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -230px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -145px;
    border: #CCC 1px solid;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 8px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 8px#000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 8px #000;
    overflow: auto;
}



    /* gallery */
#s3slider
{
    width: 500px;
 /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 300px;
 /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative;
 /* important */
    overflow: hidden;
 /* important */
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}

#s3sliderContent
{
    width: 500px;
 /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute;
 /* important */
    top: 0;
 /* important */
    margin-left: 0;
 /* important */;
}

.s3sliderImage
{
    float: left;
 /* important */
    position: relative;
 /* important */
    display: none;
 /* important */;
}

.s3sliderImage span
{
    position: absolute;
 /* important */
    left: 0;
    font: 10px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    width: 474px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
 /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
 /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
 /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    opacity: 0.7;
 /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
 /* important */
    top: 0;
 /*
        if you put top: 0;  -> the box with text will be shown 
                                at the top of the image
        if you put bottom: 0;  -> the box with text will be shown 
                                at the bottom of the image
    */;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/s3Slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Benčić Tartufi</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="buttonholder">
         <p style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">Kontakt / Contact</p>
         <p style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">O nama / About Us</p>
         <p>Proizvodi / Products</p>
         <img src="Images/Separator.png" width="600px" height="77" style="margin-left:-70px; position:relative; bottom:30px;;" />
      </div>
      <div id="dog">
         <img src="Images/dog.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
         <img src="Images/logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="textholder">
         <p>"Iz Motovunske šume na Vaš stol, <br />
            najbolji okus prirode, Tartuf."
         </p>
         <p>"From the Motovun woods to Your table,<br />
            best taste of nature, the Truffle."
         </p>
         <img src="Images/Separator.png" width="550px" height="77px" style="position:relative; bottom:30px; margin-left:-75px;" />
      </div>
      <div id="galleryholder">
         <!-- GALERIJA! DODAVAT SLIKE U IMG SRC SA SPANOM! -->
         <div id="s3slider">
            <ul id="s3sliderContent">
               <li class="s3sliderImage">
                  <img src="Slike tartufa/1.jpg">
                  <span>Hello Truffles</span>
               </li>
               <li class="s3sliderImage">
                  <img src="Slike tartufa/2.jpg">
                  <span>Hello Truffles</span>
               </li>
               <!--Kopiraj si za novu sliku!! -->
               <li class="s3sliderImage">
                  <img src="#">
                  <span>Hello Truffles</span>
               </li>
               <!--End-->
               <div class="clear s3sliderImage"></div>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!--KRAJ GALERIJE!-->
         <!--gallery holder div close-->
      </div>
      <!--end!-->
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#s3slider').s3Slider({
             timeOut: 3600
         });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you need your site to work on multiple types of devices and screen sizes, I would suggest googling responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

For what i see here you are mixing % and px in your widths and heights when you use % it will make the design fluid according the the width of the browser so remove all % and replace them with px. also I would recommend wrapping the your code in a

```
<div class="wrap"> 
.wrap{
    marging: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

It is very hard for us to help you with this code, since we cant view the images you are using. if you upload it to a website then it would be a lot easier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a fast answer.. the problem is that if i do not use % i cannot use my header to go full size? is there any other way to do it?

Comment: here are the photos i could not upload on this site because i need some 10 reputation or something: http://postimg.org/image/ocw9ckplv/ http://postimg.org/image/bcfv9bhl9/